# How to backup Firefox User Styles?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I would like to backup Firefox User Styles (from Stylish plugin) used in my installation and import later in a brand new setup. Can you suggest how to perform this operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just open [your Firefox profile](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Profiles#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile) and copy the file `stylish.sqlite`. It is a database containing your user styles, if you put it into your new profile when Firefox isn't running then Stylish will use it.